# String to int Button

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working on a math multiple choice buttons based swift app. I want to check if the selected button is the correct answer. i have the following code.

```
let sum = num1.text!.toInt()! + num2.text!.toInt()!

if btn2.titleLabel! == "\(sum)"
{
    check.text = "Right"        
}    
else 
{   
    check.text = "Wrong"
}
```

it still doesn't work when I click on a answer choice. It says wrong for all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing the actual `UILabel` object to the `sum` and not the text of the label to the sum, so try:

```
let sum = num1.text!.toInt()! + num2.text!.toInt()!

if btn2.titleLabel!.text == "\(sum)"
 {
    check.text = "Right"
}

else {
    check.text = "Wrong"
}
```

Comment: Thank You So much Juan really appreciate it and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

You should connect your buttons to an @IBAction function.
Keep the sum as an Int. No need to convert it to a String.

The function could look like this.

```
@IBAction func theButtons(sender: UIButton) {

    let p = sender.currentTitle!.toInt()
    if sum==p {
        check.text = "right"
    }
    else{
        check.text = "wrong"
    }
}
```